# .net WCF usage hosted by Windows Service

Tags: c#, wcf, windows-services

I'm relatively new into communication between applications, my goal is to have a Windows Service and somewhat a Managment Application where I can tell the service what to do, which methods to run (remote function calling). I stumbled upon "remoting", but a lot of people are telling this technique is deprecated and it's better to switch to something called WCF.

By this, I build my service according to this MSDN document:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733069.aspx

I can install the service, run it, close it. But how do I interact with it? How does an "WCF client" application has to look like? It seems like WCF is something completely different to remoting, there are no server-client interfaces, no marshalled objects. I'm a litte bit confused, hope you can help.

Comment: Continue the reading of the documentation here : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733133.aspx. But to answer to your question, WCF requires "client" code. This consists in a C# set of classes that can wrap the plumbing. You will have a "proxy" object on client side, that will act as the real instance.

Comment: @SteveB Okay, now I'm really confused again. In the documentation you showed me, the WCF service has a lot of differences to the one on my MSDN page e.g. WSHttpBinding.. or am I missing sth?

Answer (score 0):

You need have a Proxy/ChannelFactory for the client to interact with your WCF service.
On the client side you need a App.config/Web.config where you need to configure the endpoints the client has to lookfor for the service.
 You can do this programatically also.
Just go through the basics of WCF its easy than you think of it. :)
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731067.aspx